# Postgres - Copy (Stripped Double Quotes)

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, copy

I am using Postgres 8.4.4 copy, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-copy.html,  to import CSV data into my database.  Some of the values in my source data contain double-quotes which are getting stripped upon insertion whereas when I do an INSERT or UPDATE statement via psql for testing the double-quotes are retained.  Maybe giving a clue as to what is going on, some values also contain commas which are retained as needed.

I have attempted to resolve the issue base on info in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html but have had no success.

The copy command I'm using is:

```
copy my_table (field_1, field_2, field_3 ...) from '/tmp/source.csv' with csv
```

The source data is double-quoted with comma separator. This can be changed if necessary...

"value","another value","this is "another" value","no more, thanks"

Comment: The source data is double-quoted with comma separator.  This can be changed if necessary.

Comment: Please add a piece of the csv file, too.

Comment: Added, sorry it wasn't a part of the original post.

Comment: In the sample data above, the third field would be inserted as 'this is another value' (without the tics).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll have to quote the embedded quotes.
Default is double them, so your data should be:

```
"value","another value","this is ""another"" value","no more, thanks"
```

The other way is to work unquoted (but you'll have to quote the commas, if any), like

```
 value,another value,this is "another" value,no more, thanks
```

UPDATE: This works, but you'll have to make sure the embedded '"'s are quoted (in this case by adding a backslash)

```
DROP TABLE tmp.my_table CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE tmp.my_table
        ( field_1 varchar
        , field_2 varchar
        , field_3 varchar
        , field_4 varchar
        );

COPY tmp.my_table (field_1,field_2,field_3,field_4)
FROM STDIN
WITH CSV DELIMITER ',' QUOTE '"' ESCAPE '\'
        ;
"value","another value","this is \"another\" value","no more, thanks"
\.
        ;

SELECT * FROM tmp.my_table;
```

Comment: I quoted the embedded quotes as suggested which did the trick.  I did not try the other suggestion since the first worked.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: I am sorry. Because this kind of stuff is always *between systems*, one sometimes has to resort to sed scripts and worse. But a true DBA has to deal with this kind of shit. It is a fact of life, so it seems...

Comment: If you have reasonable control or at least knowledge over what characters will appear, you could choose a QUOTE character that won't appear in the text (such as '\`'). I used a similar set up with unusual QUOTE and DELIMITER characters (\` and ~ respectively) for reading a set of java .properties files (Key=value format) into a database.